# Caused by: org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: query did not return a unique result: 3

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am new in spring security and i m building a application AuthSystems using spring-security and Msql
am using extera query method in JpaRepository and that methods are not return result, and show IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException.

here is my code

## UserRepository

```
package com.ganesh.repository;


import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.ganesh.model.User;


public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    User findByUsername(String username);
        
}
```

## CustomUserDetailsService

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        
        User user = userRepo.findByUsername(username);
        
        
        CustomeUserDetail userdetails = null;
        
        if(user != null) {
            
            userdetails = new CustomeUserDetail();
            
            userdetails.setUser(user);
        
            
        }else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not fond this username"+ username);
        }
        return userdetails;
        
        
    }

}
```

## CustomeUserDetail

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class CustomeUserDetail implements UserDetails {
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8354447536649796292L;
    
    
    @Autowired
    private User user;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        
        return user.getRoles().stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+ role)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        
        return true;
    }

}
#properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/spring_auth
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.propertirs.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Please help me...

Answer (score 4):

It seems like there are multiple Users in your DB-Table with the same username. So `User findByUsername(String username);` returns more than one Result.

You could do one of the following things:

1. Make the username-Column in your DB unique.
2. Change your repository method to `List<User> findByUsername(String username);` to get all Users with that
   username.
3. Change your repository method to `User findFirstByUsername(String username);` to get just one (random) User.